# Itemdetails variable is showing less than 4

Tags: c

```
#define MAX_ITEMS 10

int wishlist, itemdetails = 1;

do
    {
        printf("How many wish list items?: ");
        scanf(" %d", &wishlist); // user input 4

        if (wishlist > MAX_ITEMS || wishlist <= 0)
        {
            printf("ERROR: List is restricted to between 1 and 10 items.\n\n");
        }
    } while (!(wishlist <= MAX_ITEMS && wishlist > 0));
   
    do
    {

        printf("\n\nItem-%d Details:\n", itemdetails);
        itemdetails++;
      
    } while (itemdetails != wishlist);
```

I don't know why the output is showing only 3 instead of 4.

Comment: You need `while (itemdetails <= wishlist)` for your second loop.

Comment: You incremented `itemdetails` after printing it, but before testing.

Comment: ahhh there we go, thank you so much!!

Comment: Replace the second `do..while` loop by a `for` loop, that makes even more sense than a `while`.